# css transition initial value

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to animate a div from right to left.

I cannot use a stylesheet because I don't know the amount of px.

If I set the initial value (where the animation starts from) and the end-value in the same function, it doesn't work.

```
//DOES NOT WORK
$("#hi").css({"width" : "200px", "transform" : "translateX(500px)"});
$("#hi").css({"transition" : "all 5s ease-out", "transform" : "translateX(0px)"});

//WORKS
$("#alsohi").css({"width" : "200px", "transform" : "translateX(500px)"});
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#alsohi").css({"transition" : "all 5s ease-out", "transform" : "translateX(0px)"});
}, 50);
```

as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c66Fb/

what is a better solution to this than using a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because both of the $("#hi") css changes are executed simultaneously, an easy way to make the first example work would be to check that the CSS properties you are setting in the first statement are actually set:

```
$("#hi").css({"width" : "200px", "transform" : "translateX(500px)"});

if ($("#hi").css("width") === "200px") {
    $("#hi").css({"transition" : "all 5s ease-out", "transform" : "translateX(0px)"});
}
```

You can see an example of this working at: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/c66Fb/1/

Another hacky way to accomplish this would be to use a while loop to do the check:

```
$("#hi").css({"width" : "200px", "transform" : "translateX(500px)"});
while ($("#hi").css("width") !== "200px") { return false; }
$("#hi").css({"transition" : "all 5s ease-out", "transform" : "translateX(0px)"});
```

The Fiddle for that one is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/c66Fb/2/

Another option (and possibly the better option from a compatibility point of view) would be to use jQuery's .animate() method, which would work with browsers that don't support CSS transforms (IE prior to 9)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Does the checking of the css property apply the first one? Is it like "flushing" the properties?

Comment: Nope, the checking is just forcing it to wait on executing the second- sort of like using setTimeout, except that instead of guessing the number of milliseconds to wait you are just tricking it into waiting a millisecond or so. In this case you are almost using the .css method like .animate, which it isn't designed to do (but I understand why you are doing it) thus the hacky sort of solution above :)

Comment: @nizzle I edited my response to show another option that will work, too. But again, for compatibility sake, I still recommend the .animate method unless earlier versions of IE are not an issue.